# Does OpenSSH >=7.2 support local-side tilde expansion for remote Unix socket forwarding

Tags: ssh, openssh, forwarding, unix-sockets

I am trying to forward a `gpg-agent` Unix socket to a remote machine. I have tried the following two versions of the remote forwarding command:

- A: `ssh -vvv -N -R ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra {HOST}`
- B: `ssh -vvv -N -R ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:/home/{USER}/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra {HOST}`

They both report successful remote forwarding after initial `ssh` connection. **However**, option A's socket fails with `debug1: connect_next: host ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra ([unix]:~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra): No such file or directory` when an actual data connection is attempted on the remote machine with `gpg-connect-agent /bye` while option B's socket works fine.

I want to know whether it is possible to do local home directory expansion with `ssh` remote forwarding command. If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` must be expanded by some program. Usually this program is the shell. The sshd daemon doesn't feed the path to a shell and doesn't expand the path.

But you don't need an expansion for the current users home directory as it is the working directory anyway.

Try

```
ssh -vvv -N -R ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:${HOME}/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra {HOST}
```

**Edit:**

This works because the working directory on the host (not on the client) is always the home directory of the target user.

The ssh server doesn't expand `~` of environment variables, but it should be possible to execute code on the host to create a link or symlink to a known location that can be used by the ssh server.

**Edited** as suggested by Kusalananda

Comment: This works if I start `ssh` session when working dir is home dir. Do you know of a way to make this work for any dir?

Comment: I added a suggestion.

Comment: The left-hand-side is the remote part, so you need to remove `~/` from there and add it to the right-hand-side.

Comment: `ssh -vvv -N -R .gnupg/S.gpg-agent:$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra {HOST}` fails, but `ssh -vvv -N -R ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra {HOST}` works. The `~` for the remote path seems significant.

Comment: Edit your answer with `ssh -vvv -N -R ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:${HOME}/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra {HOST}` and I'll accept it.

Comment: See more interesting tidbits in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The comment doesn't support newlines, so I had to put these here:

- `ssh -vvv -N -R ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:${HOME}/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra {HOST}` works
- `ssh -vvv -N -R ${HOME}/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:${HOME}/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra {HOST}` works
- `ssh -vvv -N -R ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra {HOST}` does **NOT** work
- `ssh -vvv -N -R ${HOME}/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra {HOST}` does **NOT** work

As @RalfFriedl explained in his comment (copied here verbatim), "The `${HOME}` is replaced by the client shell. This only works if `$HOME` on the client and `$HOME` on the server are the same. The `~/` is only expanded at the start of a word, not inside. So `~/XX` is `$HOME/XX`, but `XX:~/` is just `XX:~/`"

For those of you who want to automate this with the `RemoteForward` keyword in your `ssh` config file, note that there is no variable expansion there, so you need to use absolute paths. Your best bet is to create a symlink to a known location and use that path for the `ssh` config file. I'm using the same config file across multiple platform (Ubuntu, Fedora, MacOS, ...), so that's what I'll have to do.